# Laravel - difference between Controller & Model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning Laravel and I'm watching many tutorials, but I dont really get it, what's the difference between the controller and model, because you can put in both a function.

Comment: Google: "separation of concerns". That should start quite a research project.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers in Laravel are used to determine how to handle http requests.

When you have anything to do with the DB, its better to place those function in the model, and call them from the controller.

In clear terms:

1. Model performs all operations on data from DB.
2. Controller call necessary model methods and ready the data.
3. View take care of displaying the data.

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will be familiar with all of this soon.
model methods is for relationships mainly , or to make some thing for every object of this model (database table) every column in db is an object and every table is a model.
but in controller you set your app functionality that you want , and its an intermediator between model and view .
i hop this makes you good in this point.
good luck

Answer (score -1):

You can write functions anywhere, you are perfectly right.
But is not an efficient way to do things.

The answers for those questions can be easily find out. Search about MVC pattern. In few words, remember brief:

MODEL => working with relational databases / storing the data

CONTROLLER => working with the logic(taking inputs, calculus etc) / general functionalities

Combining them is more efficient than working with those together, that is the reason why using a pattern is more great than writing code in a old style mode reinventing the wheel again.

Comment: You too should probably search a bit about MVC, because what you wrote is completely wrong.

Comment: Model contains domain business logic, controllers handle user input and views handle response for user (or UI update in case of desktop apps), so, yes, it was so wrong.